# how to read blob from sql server using c#?

Tags: c#

I have a console application using C# where I want to read the blob stored in SQL Server and write it to windows file system at a specified path.

How do I convert a blob to a image of pdf using C# and write it to a file system?

Comment: @oded, I have no idea how to do it...never worked with blob...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving image from sql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697194/retrieving-image-from-sql-database)

Comment: Answers to this question for SQLite might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625029/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-a-blob-from-sqlite/625485#625485 Also, entering "sql server c# blob read" in to Google returned loads of pages of info.

Comment: And here is another good question/asnwer from SO if you are dealing with large blobs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487808/memory-effective-way-to-read-blob-data-in-c-sql-2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the blob from the database into a `byte[]` and write this buffer to a file.

Comment: blob can be of any file type is it ? how to the program recognize that its an image file or pdf file ?

Comment: @Anuya - it can't and it doesn't. You need to tell it. In most cases, when saving a blob to a database, some additional data is saved with it to identify the type (unless all files are of the same type).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:  http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_read_write_blob.html

Using a DataAdapter / DataSet would most likely prove even easier - if you can afford to have the entire BLOB content loaded into memory for the number of rows you're processing.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of blob are we talking about here? Assuming you are using .NET, Check out [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). There are other methods as well but those 2 are pretty popular. Converting to PDF you will probably need a 3rd party tool, check out [PDF Sharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/). Finally, saving to filesystem is pretty straightforward, look at the .NET [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class